# PDO prepare() in class with handler from another class

Tags: php

So, i'm using PDO (php) prepare() function in class with pdo handler from another class, but I get an error:

```
class smth{
    public static function loadData(){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :uID LIMIT 1';
        $result = config::$PDO_HANDLER->prepare($sql);// error here because of prepare
    }
}
```

how can i fix it?

error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Comment: `config::PDO_HANDLER` would be a constant. you probably want something like `config::$PDO_HANDLER` or whatever. And as a general tip, if you get an error message, TELL US what the error message it. e.g. cut 'n paste it here. saying "I got an error" can mean anything. "oops, missing `;`" all the way up to "oops, I divided by 0 and imploded the universe".

Comment: Error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Comment: so whatever PDO_HANDLER is, it's not a PDO object.

Comment: How we are supposed to know what the dependent code does?